# How to read /proc/PID/maps without sudo?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, security, capabilities

I want to read the memory map (/proc/PID/maps) of some process without being sudo.
And that is trivial, unless, the process has capabilities. See what I mean:

If I run:

```
$ bash
$ cat /proc/$$/maps
```

This works and I get the output!

But if I run:

```
sudo setcap "cap_net_raw+p" /bin/bash
```

And try the test case again:

```
$ bash
$ cat /proc/$$/maps
```

I get:

```
cat: /proc/1151842/maps: Permission denied
```

I hope this is understandable.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The ownership of the files in /proc/ is controlled by the "dumpable" flag inside the Linux kernel, which is used to prevent leaking information from a privileged process to an unprivileged user.

When the process gets capabilities it upgrades into a privileged process and /proc/ is now owned by root.

Answered in :
[Losing permissions by adding capability?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457299/losing-permissions-by-adding-capability)
and
[How to read the /proc/<pid>/fd directory of a process, which has a linux capability?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364568/how-to-read-the-proc-pid-fd-directory-of-a-process-which-has-a-linux-capabil)